# asp.net MVC3 The injection provider to Ninject.Web.Common

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, code-injection

I installed Ninject.Web.Common to Nugeto my project. (App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs)

NinjectWebCommon is not injected in the custom provider.

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private IUserRepository userRepository {get; set; } // User Table Db Context. Is injected into the injection I want here.
}
```

The Custom provider injection What can I do?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to know? What issue are you having? More importantly, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You have to either let ninject do property injection or constructor injection.
i.e.

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomMembershipProvider(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
}
```

or

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private IUserRepository userRepository;
    [Inject]
    public IUserRepository UserRepository
    {
        get{return userRepository;}
        set{userRepository = value;}
    }
}
```